# Weblogic - WLST Add Scoped Role to Domain

Tags: roles, weblogic12c, wlst

I have done extensive research on the subject of adding roles to WebLogic domain using WLST, but of no use. Is there any way or am I wasting my time...? I can add user, groups and even assign roles to users but can not find any example of adding roles to domain...!

Answer (score 1):

Wlst Sample code :

> rm=cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm().lookupRoleMapper("XACMLRoleMapper")
>
> rm.createRole(None,"TestRole",None,"")